# How To Make A File Be Named From A Texbox in VB

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to get a file to be created and named when a button is pressed. But I need the file name to contain text from a textbox.

Code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp\" + txtUser.Text + ".txt", "[" + TimeOfDay + "]" + "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + vbNewLine + "Username: " + txtUser.Text + vbNewLine + "Password: " + txtPass.Text + vbNewLine + "Secuirty: " + txtSecuirty.Text + vbNewLine + vbNewLine, True)
```

Simple Code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp\" + txtUser.Text + ".txt", {loads of stuff}, True)
```

I have loads of if functions, to stop the disallowed characters.

The error I am getting is:

```
Expression does not produce a value
```

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem.  That code works fine for me.  Is that a compile-time error or a run-time error?  What line of code causes the error?

Comment: Change code to: My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\" + txtUser.Text + ".txt", {loads of stuff}, True)

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg This is VB.NET, not C# :)

Comment: Problem is fixed! Thanks guys :)

Comment: Looks like I missed something... I just edited a few parts of it :) Thanks!! :D

Comment: @user1832160 if you've answered your own question then please add your solution as an answer so that all can share in it.

Comment: I missed typed something along the way...

Comment: @user1832160 can you please delete the question as this question will not help anybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if this will work for you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp\" + txtUser.Text.ToString() + ".txt", "test message", True)
End Sub
```

Or you can change your code to

```
Dim strFileText As String = ""
    strFileText =
        "[" & TimeOfDay.ToString() & "] " & vbCrLf &
        "Email: " & txtEmail.Text.ToString() & vbCrLf &
        "Username: " & txtUser.Text.ToString() & vbCrLf &
        "Password: " & txtPass.Text.ToString() & vbCrLf &
        "Security: " & txtSecurity.Text.ToString() & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp\" + txtUser.Text.ToString() + ".txt", strFileText, True)
```